# Is "field" a must in Redis Stream Xadd command?

Tags: redis

According Redis' document [here](https://redis.io/commands/xadd), XADD has format like below:

```
XADD key ID field value [field value ...]
```

In my use case, the format and number of the field is fixed. I wonder if I should just exclude "field" in the command?

Take an example:

Current command:

```
XADD stream * timestamp [ts_value] msg [msg_value] uid [uid_value] status [status_value]
```

New command

```
XADD stream * [ts_value] [msg_value] [uid_value] [status_value]
```

What will be the problem or will it be a bad practice if I use the "new command" considering that "fields" are fixed in my use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could work, but would not be intuitive for anyone trying to understand the data without prior knowledge - the use of field-value makes parsing the data easier. This will not only make another developer's experience harder, but would also probably mess with any kind of 3rd party application (e.g. a Redis GUI).

Also, your method will require to always have an **even** fixed number of fields.

Additionally, any future changes to the data model (yeah, nothing is really "fixed") will make maintaining this into a nightmare. You'll either have to version rows or migrate the data or who knows what.

So the real question is why would anyone want to not use field names. If you read the docs you'll find that Redis compresses the names if they repeat themselves, so there's little wastage in terms of space. The only reason I can think of is perhaps optimizing the amount of traffic, but I wouldn't go there unless it was a real issue.

Regardless, if you're hell-bent on not using field names, you can use just one and serialize all your "fixed" values into it. This will be more Redis-like, although you'd still be in trouble once the schema changes:

```
XADD stream * data "[ts_value],[msg_value],[uid_value],[status_value]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning a few very important points. The format is fixed now, but like you said, nothing is "fixed" forever, I do need to think carefully about it. Maybe keep using the standard format.